# Accessing a static method in a static variable definition

Tags: php, class, static-methods, static-variables

I am trying to access a static class method in the definition of a static class variable. I have tried several attempts, but cannot get the code to compile.

### **Naive Attempt:**

```
<?php
class TestClass {
  private static $VAR = doSomething(array());

  private static function doSomething($input) {
    return null;
  }
}
?>
```

**Error:**

```
dev@box:~/php$ php -l TestClass.php 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in TestClass.php on line 3
Errors parsing TestClass.php
```

---

### **Intuitive Attempt:**

```
<?php
class TestClass {
  private static $VAR = self::doSomething(array());

  private static function doSomething($input) {
    return null;
  }
}
?>
```

**Error:**

```
dev@box:~/php$ php -l TestClass.php 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in TestClass.php on line 3
Errors parsing TestClass.php
```

---

### **Logical Attempt:**

```
<?php
class TestClass {
  private static $VAR = static::doSomething(array());

  private static function doSomething($input) {
    return null;
  }
}
?>
```

**Error:**

```
dev@box:~/php$ php -l TestClass.php
PHP Fatal error:  "static::" is not allowed in compile-time constants in TestClass.php on line 3
Errors parsing TestClass.php
```

---

### **Desperate Attempt:**

```
<?php
class TestClass {
  private static $VAR = $this->doSomething(array());

  private static function doSomething($input) {
    return null;
  }
}
?>
```

**Error:**

```
dev@Dev08:~/php$ php -l TestClass.php 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in TestClass.php on line 3
Errors parsing TestClass.php
```

---

The task seems so simple, use the static method to define the static variable, but I can't figure out how to correctly access the static method in the context of static variable declaration.

*How do you call a static method in a static variable definition in `PHP v5.5.3`?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Correct attempt:**

```
<?php
class TestClass {
  private static $VAR = null;

  private static function doSomething($input) {
    return null;
  }
  
  public static function Construct(){
      self::$VAR = self::doSomething(array());
  }
}
TestClass::Construct();
?>
```

You CAN initialize a static to a scalar and an array. You CAN NOT initialize it with a function call. So you need a public method that can be invoked to initialize statics if you need things to be private.

If they were public, you could have done:

```
TestClass::$VAR = TestClass::doSomething(array());
```

right after the class declaration or when you want to instantiate it.

**PROOF**

> Like any other PHP static variable, **static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed**. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object. **[from PHP.net/Static](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)**

Comment: Can you reference the PHP docs on the 'only a scalar and an array' specification?

Comment: @awashburn Seriously?! I think your PHP interpreter showed you that. Why do you think those errors pop up? --- Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy, correct, referenced, & well formatted answer :)

Comment: @awashburn If you want to know why, it's mainly because statics initialize on parse, but an expression may be dependent on external stuff so you are asked to choose when initialization is done for a static.

Comment: That makes sense, I have gotten the impression that PHP's interpreter isn't that robust.